# Discord.js: using Nicknames instead of Usernames

Tags: discord.js

I've used the beginner guides out there to get started on a simple bot for our guild discord. But, for the love of me, I cannot find a way for the bot to refer to server specific nicknames instead of usernames.

The code looks somewhat like this:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Pong! was returned to user with nickname ' + ????????????.nickname
                });
            break;
         }
     }
}
```

Anyone know what the command/variable is to retrieve nicknames instead of usernames?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question, but if I understood correctly. You need get member.nickname in reply message.

At the first `bot.on('message' =>` event return only [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message) object.

For reply on the same channel you can use `message.channel.send('text')`
If you need get member Nickname you can use [`member.displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) its will return member server nickname, or member username + tag if member has no nickname

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'ping':
                message.channel.send(`Pong! was returned to user with nickname  ${message.member.displayName}`)
                break;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Much appreciated.

It does not respond to the !ping command now. Do you think it is possible without changing the function call? (or whatever the terminology is)

So that "bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt)" remains the same? In further development I've begun using those user, userID etc. inputs :)

Comment: It looks very strange, try reading the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#resulting-code) for the correct handle commands